# Elasticsearch returns unmatched results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am newbie to ELasticsearch and would need your help regarding ES returning unmatched results for analyzed field. 
i have a custom analyzer as follows:

```
 "analyzer": {
            "testing_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "char_filter": "html_strip",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "snowball",
                  "stop"
               ]
            },
            "testing_search_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "char_filter": "html_strip",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
```

i have set this analyzer for a field on both index & search as follows.

```
"name":
{
"type": "string",
"analyzer": "testing_analyzer",
"search_analyzer": "testing_search_analyzer"
}
```

but when search for name "università di bologna", it return first result record have same match, but some other records not match (2nd record in result below):

Record1:

```
 [ "Universit&agrave; di Bologna", "University of Bologna", "CNR", "Universit&agrave; di Pisa", "University of Pisa", "Mineraria e Delle Tecnologie Ambientali" ]
```

Record2:

```
[ "University of Salerno", "Universit&agrave; di Salerno" ]
```

Query :

```
 {
   "fields": [
      "doc_id",
      "name"
   ],
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "name": "Università di bologna"
      }
   }
}
```

any help ?!

Comment: how is  `testing_search_analyzer` defined ?

Comment: "testing_search_analyzer":
                {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": "html_strip" ,
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                },

Comment: can you show the query too ?

Comment: curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/users/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
"fields" : ["doc_id" , "name"],
"query": {
"match": { "name": "Università di bologna" }
 }
}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are as expected. 
By default the match query does an 'OR' of the tokens generated by `tokenizer`.

Try changing the query to following:

```
{
   "fields": [
      "doc_id",
      "name"
   ],
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "name": {
            "query": "Università di bologna",
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it worked after adding "and" operator as instructed!!! thank you so much. BTW why without adding "and" operator some records that does not have exact search term had higher score than the ones with exact match?

Comment: try turning on [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) it may hint as to why this could be happening

Comment: also if the answer was helpfu do upvote & accept thanks :)

Comment: sure np!  it doesn't look like it got accepted :) but whenever you get a chance thanks.

Comment: just did :) please could you confirm?